# How can we differentiate between a secondary and shared calendar in Google Calendar API response

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a query with respect to the Calendar List API for Google Calendar:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/list

We have a scenario where user1 has shared his calendar with user2 with **Make Changes and Manage Sharing** permission.

Now if we invoke the list calendar API on user2, we receive a response as below:

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
  "etag": "\"<redacted>\"",
  "id": "user1@gmail.com",
  "summary": "user1@gmail.com",
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "colorId": "4",
  "backgroundColor": "#fa573c",
  "foregroundColor": "#000000",
  "accessRole": "owner",
  "defaultReminders": [],
  "conferenceProperties": {
    "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
      "hangoutsMeet"
    ]
  }
}
```

We can see that the access role above for the user1's calendar is owner and the primary value is absent(false).

Now if user2 has a secondary calendar we again see something similar in the listcalendar API response:

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
  "etag": "\"<redacted>\"",
  "id": "<redacted>@group.calendar.google.com",
  "summary": "Secondary Calendar",
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "colorId": "1",
  "backgroundColor": "#ac725e",
  "foregroundColor": "#000000",
  "selected": true,
  "accessRole": "owner",
  "defaultReminders": [],
  "conferenceProperties": {
    "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
      "hangoutsMeet"
    ]
  }
}
```

Access role above for the secondary calendar is owner and the primary value is absent(false).

So how can we differentiate between a secondary and shared calendar for user2? We require the same for some specific processing in our application.

Comment: Why is the id not enough to differentiate between calendars? user1 => id1 | user2 => id2

Comment: Hi Emel, we have no prior info on the user. We need to figure out from the Calendar List API response, which calendars and shared calendars(shared to him by any other user) and which calendars he owns(primary). For primary calendars this is easy as we have a field for that. But there is nothing to distinguish between shared and secondary calendars. At least we are not aware of the same.

Comment: Don't you have any other form of control other than those provided by the API response? For example, a DB to store the relationship between ID and emails.

Comment: No, we don't have such a mapping available as our only source of information is the Google API response.

Comment: The only field that seems different to me, is the `id` that contains the email of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments there does not seem to be a clear way to differentiate the secondary calendars, except for the `id` and the appearance of the `primary` field.

Without having a database to control it, it does not seem to be possible to differentiate between a secondary calendar and a shared calendar, except for the calendar id.

You can use [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=823906) to explain your case to Google and ask to always have a field where you specify the calendar owner or another element that allows you to identify it.

Comment: Thanks Emel, I had raised https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237313774 for the same.
Any idea if there is a way to escalate/ expedite the issue with concerned teams.

Comment: You have to wait for Google to answer your question. Consider up-vote and accept the answer

Comment: If you have a Google domain, you can open a [Google Workspace Support Case](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10759436?hl=en)